# Python 2.7- Remove redundant elements in list But retain order

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, collections

I am trying to remove redundant elements from list by using collections.Counter
but it return a dict, when i try to get keys they are sorted, example

```
import collections 
aa=[55,0,1,55,4,7,8]
s=collections.Counter(aa)
print s
print s.keys()
```

Output :

```
Counter({55: 2, 0: 1, 1: 1, 4: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1})

[0, 1, 4, 7, 8, 55]
```

Though i have check collections.counter is subclass of dictionary (dict)

> https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html
>   which states
>
> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects

I am unable to understand when its keys are in order which i want but doing

> s.keys()
>   gives sorted keys

Comment: can't understand what is your problem?

Comment: @amitKarnik i am confused if counter is returning me a subclass of dict with retaining order.. when i get keys from s.keys() it sorts them why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the keys based on their positions in the original list:

```
sorted( s.keys(), key=lambda v:aa.index(v))
```

Comment: thank you it works, can you also explain me if collections.counter is returning dict with keys with retaining order but when i get s.keys() it return sorted array of keys

Comment: They don't always come back sorted; yours was a pretty small example.

Comment: That is what i want to know what is the reason and case when they come sorted and when not @Scott Hunter

Comment: You got (un)lucky; the bigger the list, the less likely the list will be sorted.

Comment: Is there any rule regarding this in Python ? @scott Hunter

Comment: The laws of probability.